# Do SQL Server Connections closed on restarting IIS?

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-7

Due to connection leak there were hundreds of connection open on my dev-server. I fixed the connection leak, deployed it and restarted the IIS server, but It didn't seems to be closing old sql connection.

### So, I wanted to know, if restarting IIS, closes the old sql connections.

Comment: this is interesting. I think connection pool is managed by IIS so restarting IIS should release all of them. waiting to see an answer

Answer (score -1):

did you restart the website or application pool ?

Try restarting the Application Pool associated to your website.

Note: You mentioned development, please make sure you are not using Express IIS. Sometimes VStudio points to Express IIS instead of Local IIS

Comment: Application Pool, and no, I'm not using Express IIS.

Comment: No,I had to kill all process using query.